# Parameter 'Web' is obsolete. The -Web parameter will be removed in a future release. Use Connect-PnPOnline -Url [subweburl] instead to connect

Tags: development, powershell, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have this PnP Power-shell to loop through all sites >> then all libraries >> then list all the main folders inside the libraries.

```
$AdminUrl = "https://****-admin.sharepoint.com/"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminUrl -Interactive 
 
#sharepoint online get all site collections PowerShell
$SiteColl = Get-PnPTenantSite
$csvOutput = @()
 
#sharepoint online PowerShell iterate through all site collections
ForEach($Site in $SiteColl)
{
 
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Site.Url -Interactive
   $Webs = Get-PnPSubWeb -Recurse -IncludeRootWeb
               
               
    #Get All document libraries
ForEach($Web in $Webs)
    {
               $DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList -Web $Web | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Title -ne "Site Assets" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false}
    #Iterate through each document library
    ForEach($Library in $DocumentLibraries)
               {
               #Get all Subfolders of a folder - recursively
              $SubFolders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $Library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl -ItemType Folder #-Recursive
               
               ForEach($folder in $SubFolders)
               {
               
                Write-Host $Site.Title " --> "  $Library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl " --> " $folder.Name " --> " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl
                $csvOutput +=  [PsCustomObject]@{SiteTitle = $Site.Title; LibraryTitle = $Library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl; Folder = $folder.Name; FolderPath = $folder.ServerRelativeUrl}

               }
               
               }
}
 
 
}
$csvOutput | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "D:\export123.csv"
```

The script is working fine, but i am getting this warning:-

> WARNING: Parameter 'Web' is obsolete. The -Web parameter will be
> removed in a future release. Use Connect-PnPOnline -Url [subweburl]
> instead to connect to a subweb.

so what i need to modify to make my code future proof?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `-Web` parameter is no longer a listed parameter on the [Get-PnPList](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPList.html) documentation. I would suggest you not use this parameter and instead use the `-Identity` parameter, as defined in the documentation for this cmdlet.

Comment: so can i pass the Url for the Web inside the `-Identity` parameter ?

Comment: It's in the documentation: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPList.html#example-3

Comment: but how i can do this inside my code,, as i am returning the list automatically

Comment: Also in the documentation: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPList.html#example-4

Comment: now instead of passing the `Web` as paramter, i connect to it as follow:- `Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Web.Url -Interactive` then i get all the libraries inside the current web (without having to explicitly define it), as follow:- `$DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList  | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Title -ne "Site Assets" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false}`

Comment: does this sound valid?

Comment: You might want to return the connection and then use the connection parameter of Get-PnPList to specify the site connection but yes, it seems like what you have there could work.

Comment: can you advice more on what do you exactly men by `You might want to return the connection and then use the connection parameter of Get-PnPList to specif`

Comment: This is off topic from the question, I'm referring to the -ReturnConnection parameter that allows you to return the site connection from Connect-PnPOnline and the -Connection parameter on PnP cmdlets that lets you specify the site connection to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would be something like

```
ForEach($Web in $Webs) {
    $webConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $web.Url -ClientId $clientID -ClientSecret $clientSecret -returnConnection
    $DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList -connection $webConnection | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Title -ne "Site Assets" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false}
```

You'd not to authenticate interactively for every web, so app credentials is used